# toggle other div when clicked on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do i toggle the other div to close when a button is clicked?

```js
$(".slider-wrapper button").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".slider-content").slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-wrapper">
  <button>OPEN ME</button>
  <div class="slider-content">Foo</div>
</div>

<div class="slider-wrapper">
  <button>OPEN ME</button>
  <div class="slider-content">Foo</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
$(".slider-wrapper button").click(function() {
  $(".slider-content:visible").add($(this).next()).slideToggle();
});
```

It will hide those that are visible and show the one that corresponds to the button you clicked.

**demo**

```js
$(".slider-wrapper button").click(function() {
  $(".slider-content:visible").add($(this).next()).slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-wrapper">
  <button>OPEN ME</button>
  <div class="slider-content">Foo</div>
</div>

<div class="slider-wrapper">
  <button>OPEN ME</button>
  <div class="slider-content">Foo</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with javascript,

```html
<div class="slider-wrapper">
    <button id="btn1" onClick="myFunction()" >btn 1</button>
    <div id="div1" style="display: block;" class="slider-content">Foo</div>
</div>

<div class="slider-wrapper">
    <button id="btn2" onClick="myFunction()" >btn 2</button>
    <div id="div2" style="display: block;"  class="slider-content">Foo</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction() {


       var btn1= document.getElementById("btn1");
       var btn2= document.getElementById("btn2");

       var div1= document.getElementById("div1");
       var div2= document.getElementById("div2");

       btn1.onclick = function() {
         div1.style.display = "block";
         div2.style.display = "none";
       };

       btn2.onclick = function() {
         div1.style.display = "none";
         div2.style.display = "block";
       };


}

</script>
```

Comment: Your answer does not provide a "slideToggle" effect and your code is not very dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can make It very simple Jquery :

```js
$(".slider-wrapper button").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().siblings(".slider-wrapper").children(".slider-content").slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-wrapper">
  <button>OPEN ME</button>
  <div class="slider-content">Foo</div>
</div>

<div class="slider-wrapper">
  <button>OPEN ME</button>
  <div class="slider-content">Foo</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Think you need to read this again `How do i toggle the other div to close when a button is clicked`

Comment: You can Use : $(this).next().slideToggle();

Comment: Are you want , When I click a button then toggle other div. Not this div right?

Comment: Dude's not my question, I'm just trying to help you by telling you that the answer you provided doesn't solve the Problem the OP is facing. Look at my example to see what it should do.

Comment: I still don't believe that OP is looking for this behavior. But I'll let the OP comment on that.